# how to design asynchronous web services

Tags: service, apache-axis

How to design asynchronous web services? That means each web service wait for the reply from another one asynchronously?

Can anyone give me any clue?

Answer (score 0):

provide the service with a callback ... so that:

```
service1 => service2.DoSomething();
// at a later time
service2 => service1.DoSomethingCallback(result);
```

Comment: :P. 
Generally, which technology can be used to transport messages among WSs asynchronously. jms?custominzed message? spread queue? 
especially,when tranversal of services using a ring network?

Are there any examples available? THanks